# Merge 2 videos with a horizontal 10px border between them

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing

I am using the following command to marge 2 videos side by side.

```
ffmpeg -i left.mp4 -i right.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v:0]pad=iw*2:ih[bg]; [bg][1:v:0]overlay=w" output.mp4
```

How I can give a 10px white border or space (horizontaly) in between two videos?

Answer (score 3):

[image]
<sub>Example with 10 pixel white padding separating the overlay. (Click for better view.)</sub>

```
"[0:v:0]pad=(iw*2)+10:ih:color=white[bg]; [bg][1:v:0]overlay=w+10"
```